# Lenovo Ideapad 330 dual booting problem

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

I am having problem while dual booting my Lenovo ideapad 330, currently installed with Windows 10 using usb flash drive.

[It shows the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5v2A.jpg):

`[  10.682893] Problem loading UEFI:db X.509 certificate(-65)
[  10.683127] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
[  14.263853] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: failed to create kernel channel, -22
(initramfs) Unable to find a medium contaning a live file system`

Please help.